# Setting a custom FireFox location for geckodriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Is there a way to set a system property that actually tells the computer that Firefox is not located in the default location?

I have it installed on drive E:, not on C:, so I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS
>   appears to be: WIN8 Build info: version: 'unknown', revision:
>   '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info: host:
>   'BlueWater', ip: '10.0.0.181', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info:
>   driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the `binary` capability within the `moz:firefoxOptions` desired capability. See [the geckodriver readme](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#firefox-capabilities)

Comment: So how do I get to the binary capability? Sorry I am so new to this.

Comment: Pass the desired capabilities to your driver
`{ "moz:firefoxOptions": { "binary": "E:\\path\\to\\firefox" } }`